# Http POST in swift always gives me a 400 error

Tags: swift

This is my first time programming in Swift and i am not able to get an HTTP Post to work. I've compared this with similar code that worked in Objective-C. When i make the same call from a browser test tool, i get 200OK. My logs for the backend service i am calling show that the body size is 0 (so nothing is going in the body of the request). What am i doing wrong?

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "URL");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
let postString = "firstName=James&lastName=Bond";
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(request.HTTPBody)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
      data, response, error in
    println("response = \(response)")
    if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
    }

task.resume()
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? I tested the code, and it works.

Comment: I get a 400 response and the logs show the body is empty. I haven't tried on a device yet. Do I need to do anything special on the emulator to make this work? This is for a Watchkit application and this is the watchkit extension code.